# Polar coordinate area

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

Find the area of the small loop of the graph of $r = 2 + 2 \sqrt{2} \sin \theta.$

What do they mean by the small loop, and how do I find the endpoints and area?

Comment: Draw the curve.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+r%3D2%2B2sqrt%282%29sin%28theta%29

Answer (score 1):

Find the area of the small loop of $r=2+2\sqrt{2}\sin(\theta)$.

First, set r=0 and solve for theta, since this is where shapes start and stop it will let us find our bounds.
$$0=2+2\sqrt{2}\sin(\theta)$$
$$-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}=\sin(\theta)$$
Looking at our unit circle we know that,

$$\theta=\frac{5\pi}{4}, \frac{7\pi}{4}$$

Since we want the area of the small section, we set our bounds for theta to the smallest possible interval:
$$\frac{5\pi}{4} \rightarrow \frac{7\pi}{4}$$

Then evaluate the integral,
$$\int_{\frac{5\pi}{4}}^{\frac{7\pi}{4}} \int_0^{2+2\sqrt{2}\sin(\theta)}  r \ dr \ d\theta$$
In Calculus 2 terms: 
$$\frac{1}{2}\int_ {\frac{5\pi}{4}}^{\frac{7\pi}{4}} (2+2\sqrt{2}\sin(\theta))^2 \ d\theta$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  This is hard to read.  Your posts will look a lot better if you only put the math in MathJax.  Use `{text}` only for little snippets inside the math that shouldn't be set in math italics.  Find a post that looks good to you, and click on the "edit" button to see how they did it.

Comment: @saulspatz Thanks, I think it’s fixed

Comment: Ah yes, this is much easier to read.  Thanks.